# Cannot install python-devel on Fedora

Tags: python, python-2.7, fedora, rpm

I am trying to install python-devel. I can't do it through yum, no matter what I try, so I just tried to install it via `rpm -i` and I get this error. What is even going on here?

```
[me@localhost]~% rpm -i python-devel-2.7.10-10.fc24.x86_64.rpm
warning: python-devel-2.7.10-10.fc24.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 81b46521: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    python(x86-64) = 2.7.10-10.fc24 is needed by python-devel-2.7.10-10.fc24.x86_64
    python-macros = 2.7.10-10.fc24 is needed by python-devel-2.7.10-10.fc24.x86_64
    python < 2.7.10-10.fc24 conflicts with python-devel-2.7.10-10.fc24.x86_64
[me@localhost]~% python --version
Python 2.7.10
[me@localhost]~% yum install python-macros
Last metadata expiration check performed 0:58:14 ago on Thu Oct  8 14:40:20 2015.
Package python-macros-2.7.10-8.fc22.noarch is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Comment: the package you got for manual installation with yum, is version 2.7.10-10 from rawhide (f24); you are on f22 and have python-2.7.10-8. You should get python-devel-2.7.10-8.fc22 , OR report the initial problem you were having with yum, and in any case, this question is off-topic here.

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ why is this question off-topic?

Comment: Because you should not call rpm directly. And definitelly to not mix F24 and F22 packages. 'dnf install python-devel' should not work. If not solve that issue, not the one posted here.

Comment: @msuchy I have no idea why any of the things you said are true.

Comment: why should I not call rpm directly?